# ¿Cómo obtener un valor de una columna de una tabla y pasarla a una variable para luego insertar en otra tabla? PDO

Tags: postgresql, pdo, variables, select, insert

espero que se encuentren bien. Tengo una duda que me ha frustrado en estos dos últimos días. El punto es que estoy haciendo un CRUD para registros, los cuales van a insertar datos por medio de un formulario. Estoy utilizando un formato json en un archivo js para encapsular todas las variables y datos que arroje el formulario, así luego mandarlos a un archivo específico de PHP destinado a las acciones del CRUD. El punto está en que tengo dos tablas, una de innovador que se podría decir que es una tabla madre, y otra de datos_residencia (que tiene como FK el ID de la tabla madre) de una relación de 1 a 1. En el caso del CRUD, al momento de ejecutar por medio de switch el caso de ALTA de registros (Creación) se insertan correctamente los datos de la tabla madre, pero no se insertan los de las tabla de datos_residencia porque al no darle un valor a la clave foranea de por si me impide realizar la inserción. Es por eso que me puse a pensar en realizar un SELECT y extraer el último ID insertado una vez se hayan insertado los datos de la tabla madre, extraer ese ID y ponerlo en una variable para luego realizar otro INSERT pero en la tabla de datos_residencia. No sé que es lo que está mal... Agradecería un montón cualquier ayuda

Este es el código del php, lo que quiero resaltar es en la parte de switch en el caso 1 que se activa al crear un registro. Sí se insertan los valores en la tabla de innovadores, pero hasta ahí llega a funcionar, lo demás no se realiza. Cabe destacar que pongo un ORDER BY ya que el formulario se insertan ya todos los datos, así que en teoría si uso el último ID ordenado descendentemente, estaría usando el mismo que requiero para la otra tabla. Gracias de antemano y disculpen si el post no está bien formulado, soy nuevo en la plataforma.

```
    <?php

include_once('conexion.php');
$objeto = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objeto->Conectar();

//RECEPCIÓN DE LOS DATOS ENVIADOS POR EL MÉTODO POST DESDE EL ARCHIVO JS

//TABLA PARA DATOS GENERALES
$nacionalidad = (isset($_POST['nacionalidad'])) ? $_POST['nacionalidad'] : '';
$cedula = (isset($_POST['cedula'])) ? $_POST['cedula'] : '';
$pasaporte = (isset($_POST['pasaporte'])) ? $_POST['pasaporte'] : '';
$primer_nombre = (isset($_POST['primer_nombre'])) ? $_POST['primer_nombre'] : '';
$segundo_nombre = (isset($_POST['segundo_nombre'])) ? $_POST['segundo_nombre'] : '';
$primer_apellido = (isset($_POST['primer_apellido'])) ? $_POST['primer_apellido'] : '';
$segundo_apellido = (isset($_POST['segundo_apellido'])) ? $_POST['segundo_apellido'] : '';
$sexo = (isset($_POST['sexo'])) ? $_POST['sexo'] : '';
$fecha_nacimiento = (isset($_POST['fecha_nacimiento'])) ? $_POST['fecha_nacimiento'] : '';
$edo_civil = (isset($_POST['edo_civil'])) ? $_POST['edo_civil'] : '';
$es_indigena = (isset($_POST['es_indigena'])) ? $_POST['es_indigena'] : '';
$pueblo_indigena = (isset($_POST['pueblo_indigena'])) ? $_POST['pueblo_indigena'] : '';
//TABLA PARA RESIDENCIA
$estado = (isset($_POST['estado'])) ? $_POST['estado'] : '';
$municipio = (isset($_POST['municipio'])) ? $_POST['municipio'] : '';
$parroquia = (isset($_POST['parroquia'])) ? $_POST['parroquia'] : '';
$cod_postal = (isset($_POST['cod_postal'])) ? $_POST['cod_postal'] : '';
$telefono = (isset($_POST['telefono']) && !empty($_POST['telefono'])) ? $_POST['telefono'] : NULL;
$celular = (isset($_POST['celular'])) ? $_POST['celular'] : '';


$opcion = (isset($_POST['opcion'])) ? $_POST['opcion'] : '';


switch($opcion){

    case 1: //ALTA - INSERTAR DATOS
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO innovadores (nacionalidad, cedula, pasaporte, primer_nombre, segundo_nombre, primer_apellido, segundo_apellido, sexo, fecha_nacimiento, edo_civil, es_indigena, pueblo_indigena) VALUES('$nacionalidad', '$cedula', '$pasaporte', '$primer_nombre', '$segundo_nombre', '$primer_apellido', '$segundo_apellido', '$sexo', '$fecha_nacimiento', '$edo_civil', '$es_indigena', '$pueblo_indigena')";          
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute();
      
            $consulta = "SELECT id_innovador FROM innovadores ORDER BY id_innovador DESC LIMIT 1";
            $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
            $resultado->execute();
            $id_innovador = $resultado->fetchColumn();

            $consulta = "INSERT INTO datos_residencia (estado, municipio, parroquia, cod_postal, telefono, celular, id_innovador) VALUES ('$estado', '$municipio', '$parroquia', '$cod_postal', '$telefono', '$celular','$id_innovador')";
            $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
            $resultado->execute();
        
            $consulta = "SELECT * FROM innovadores, datos_residencia ORDER BY id_innovador DESC LIMIT 1";
            $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
            $resultado->execute();

            $data=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    break;
    }
print json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);//envio el array final el formato json a AJAX
$conexion=null;

?>
```

Comment: Esto es más fácil hacerlo con un store procedure en lugar de código

Comment: No entiendo qué quieres decir con esto: *porque al no darle un valor a la clave foranea de por si me impide realizar la inserción*. De todos modos, la mejor forma de resolver esto es a nivel de la base de datos, programando un TRIGGER que se dispare cuando ocurra un `INSERT` en `innovadores`, insertando una nueva fila en la tabla dependiente. En cuanto al código, bastaría con implementar un control de errores, cosa que no haces. Un programa que no maneja los errores no será nunca un programada maduro.

Comment: Con eso me refiero a que si no le doy un valor a esa columna donde está la clave foranea, no va a realizar la inserción de los demás datos porque es obligatorio. ¿Con lo del trigger a qué te refieres? ¿con esa sentencia es posible insertar el mismo valor de la tabla innovadores a la tabla dependiente? Una disculpa por mis novatadas, soy estudiante de informática y sigo en proceso de aprender este tipo de cosas, verdaderamente muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo de responder y darme sugerencias, desconocia lo que me acaban de comentar. @A.Cedano

Comment: Sí, el `TRIGGER` es un programa almacenado que se dispara de forma automática cuando algo ocurre. Hay varios tipos. Por ejemplo, si programas uno del tipo `AFTER INSERT` sobre una determinada tabla, el TRIGGER se disparará cada vez que insertes una fila en esa tabla y hará lo que haya indicado en el programa (en este caso insertar una nueva fila en la tabla dependiente). Para más detalles consulta [aquí](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/) y para ver un ejemplo del tipo `AFTER INSERT` consulta [aquí](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/mysql-after-insert-trigger/).

Comment: OJO: Los `TRIGGER` se programan en la base de datos, no en PHP. Ahora mismo, al intentar hacer esto en PHP (con mucha dificultad) lo que haces es tirar a PHP un problema que podrías y deberías resolver en la base de datos con 4 o 5 líneas de código. El TRIGGER se programa y se dispara sólo, en PHP sólo te preocupas por hacer el INSERT en la tabla principal.

Comment: Okey, perfecto ¡Muchas gracias por la información brindada! y sobretodo por guiarme a los sitios de documentación. Estaré primeramente documentandome acerca de cómo funciona el TRIGGER para así luego ver como implementarlo en el caso que deseo hacer, en cuanto lo ejecute le avisaré de los resultados.

Comment: Perfecto, aunque apenas ahora vi que tienes la etiqueta `postgresql` en tu pregunta y los enlaces que te pasé antes son de MySQL. Te dejo aquí los enlaces para PostgreSQL: `TRIGGER` en la [doc. oficial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html), y también [tutorial de introducción](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-triggers/) y también [tutorial con ejemplos prácticos](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-triggers/creating-first-trigger-postgresql/).